# iTextSharp generated PDF works in browser but not after download

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a PDF which is generated by iTextSharp in C# - it's a template PDF, which gets some additional lines of text added using stamper, then pushed to S3 and finally returned to the browser as a file stream (using mvc.net).

The newly added lines work fine when the PDF is viewed in the browser (Chrome), but when I download the PDF and open it locally (with Preview or Adobe Acrobat on Mac), only the template is showing, and the newly added lines are gone.

What could cause this?

Here's a code example: (condensed)

```
using(var receiptTemplateStream =    GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XXXXX.DepositReceipts.Receipt.pdf"    ))
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(receiptTemplateStream);

    var outputPdfStream = new MemoryStream();
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream) { FormFlattening = true, FreeTextFlattening = true };
    var _pbover = stamper.GetOverContent(1);



    using (var latoLightStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XXXXX.DepositReceipts.Fonts.Lato-Light.ttf"))
    using (var latoLightMS = new MemoryStream())
    {

        _pbover.SetFontAndSize(latoLight, 11.0f);
        var verticalPosition = 650;

        _pbover.ShowTextAligned(0, account.company_name, 45, verticalPosition, 0);
        verticalPosition = verticalPosition - 15;


        var filename = "Receipt 0001.pdf";

        stamper.SetFullCompression();
        stamper.Close();

        var file = outputPdfStream.ToArray();
        using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            output.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            output.Position = 0;

            var response = await _s3Client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                InputStream = output,
                BucketName = "XXXX",
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,
                Key = filename
            });
        }

        return filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downloading as a stream is the same thing as downloading it locally. Show us the code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidG, you are most likely right, but potentially in-browser rendering engine can produce results that differ from the rendering engine whatever program the OP uses for opening the PDF after the download.

Comment: I've added the code example now.

Comment: I just tested the PDF... It looks fine in Chrome and Firefox on Mac, but when viewing it in Safari, I get the same problem as with Preview and Acrobat.

Comment: When you are downloading it via the browser, is this via the MVC app?  Have you tried downloading the file directly from S3 and testing the file works. You may have an issue with the MVC functionality.

Comment: @AdamCarr Yes, that also doesn't work. It is definitely with the itextSharp part. I also checked in Windows and that's the same issue.

Comment: I found this issue, which mentions writer.flush(), but I don't have a writer in this code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955224/generating-blank-pdf-when-downloaded-itextsharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This was a funky one!

I had another method in the same solution that worked without problems. It turns out that the template PDF, that I load and write my content over, was the issue.

The template I used was generated in Adobe Illustrator. I had another one which was generated in Adobe Indesign - which worked.

When I pulled this template pdf into Indesign, and then exported it again (from Indesign) it suddenly worked.

I'm not sure exactly what caused this issue, but it must be some sort of encoding.